# Removing minor ticks in x-axis of semilogx plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Here is an example of code

```
x = 0:1000;
y = log(x);
semilogx(x,y)
```

[image: semilogx picture]

I want to remove the small tick marks between 10^0 and 10^1 on the x-axis.

I tried:

```
set(gca,'XminorTick','off')
```

but it didn't work

Comment: I think this might be a bug with MATLAB's `'log'` axes scaling.

Comment: Well, maybe not a bug, since you really should have minor ticks to make it clear that a log scale is being used, but at the very least it should be documented that they're forced on for log scales. It seems like it was introduced with HG2 in R2014b, since this behavior isn't present in R2014a.

Comment: As of R2016b the command given by the OP actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no good way to do this for good reason. It is always best to make it explicit that a log scale is used for a plot.

If you really want, the easiest thing to do would be to perform a log transform on your data and plot it on a regular linear scale. Then specify custom tick labels to make it appear to be a logarithmic scale.

```
%// Plot after performing log transform of your xdata
plot(log10(x), y)

%// Tick locations
ticks = 0:3;

%// Create custom tick labels
labels = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('10^%d', x), ticks, 'uni', 0);

%// Update the ticks and ticklabels
set(gca, 'xtick', ticks, 'XTickLabels', labels)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The `m` and `o` must be capital.

```
set(gca,'XMinorTick','Off')
```

This works for me in a semilogx plot.

Comment: This is not OP’s problem. This was a bug in a particular version of MATLAB that is fixed in newer versions. In general, property names are not case sensitive.